# How to change the time span for Trend report generated by Jenkins JaCoCo Code Coverage Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jacoco

While using Jenkins JaCoCo Code Coverage plugin, it automatically shows a Code Coverage Trend with the build. By default that happens for each build i.e. it shows coverage trend after each build. I would like to see the coverage trend after each Sprint (I want to modify that part of the trend graph).